Meaning of 'You did good business" in relation to a dog
While I was watching the movie "Fatal Attraction", I heard the phrase "You did good business" said to the dog as shown below.

I found the correct meaning of business in  dictionaries in Merriam-Webster and Urban Dictionary
I have questions on this.

I thought "you did a good job" was more appropriate. Could that "you did a good job" be used instead?
If you put 'the' in front of the 'business' as in 'You did the good business', Is that the same meaning or does that take on different meaning?
Is this expression also used for us human beings? If not, what meaning or property of the word 'business' would cause this to used only for pets?  Would there be any reason?

Thank you very much.

The whole thing is pretty bad. A dog (or at times, a cat) is said to do its business. But generally, we don't say it like in that movie. You might say: Well, boy, you did your business, didn't you? For example. You did good business, just sounds weird.

This is just the kind of nonsense speech people use with dogs. They don't understand what you're saying, so the important thing is that you're saying it in a positive and affirming tone of voice. Please don't use this kind of thing as a guide for how you should talk to humans.

The euphemism 'do one's business' has been used of people for centuries, as explained here. In fact, I saw it used recently in the instructions for flushing a toilet on a boat. I suppose we are more likely to speak of such matters in relation to pets than people, except in a medical or childcare context!

@KateBunting Wanna combine that with YonKuma's observation to form a full answer?

Let's get the idiom right: do its business is for animals, not humans. At least, traditionally regardless of what websites might say.

A Scottish person might very well say 'You did a good job' to a dog.

@YonKuma dogs might be unable to speak English, but they understand a lot of words (but not complex ideas). You don't have to put on the "stupid child" voice, they'll get it. For that matter, you don't have to do it with childen either, or blind people.

@WeatherVane While you don't have to, people often use "cutesy" voice when talking to their dogs. "You're such a good boy, aren't you, aren't you?" It's not quite the same as "motherese" but I suspect there's similar psychology.

@WeatherVane - You say 'Bonzo, I don't want you to go on the carpet any more. OK, Bonzo? Be a good boy, Bonzo!'. What your dog hears is 'Bonzo blah blah bla Bonzo blah blah Bonzo'.

My colleague had a neighbour who used to rant at her dog for 'not understanding English'.

@MichaelHarvey I thought "but not complex ideas" covered that. But at the house of some people I visited, their dog had done its business in the centre of the lounge carpet and was looking pleased with itself, not ashamed. It was its way of answering back, a revenge attack, and everybody was accusing others of having annoyed the dog. So nobody had cleared it up. They are sentient creatures even if they don't brush up their Shakespeare.

...and quite often, it is the humans who don't understand their dog.

I know it's distasteful but the question should really say what you found in the dictionary. For all we know, you might think the dog opened a print shop.

Thank you all for making comments.  So, 'do one's business' has 2 meanings as a euphemism: have sex and defecate.  Thank you.

I have never heard 'do one's business' used as a euphemism for 'have sex', and I think I'd probably dislike a person who used it that way.

It is defined as "UK slang: to have sex" in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/do-the-business


(MW) a bowel movement —used especially of pets

I assume this is the definition you found.  As the definition says "especially of pets" so not normally of humans. It is a euphemism, to avoid saying "poo" or something worse.
You might say "the dog did its business on the rug".
The wording in the movie is odd, but people say odd things to animals (who don't answer back) Learners of English shouldn't overthink this.  You don't need to learn to speak English to a dog.

James K,  thank you very much for the answer.
